# Doctrine automatically create all the database tables?

Tags: doctrine-orm

is there any way to tell doctrine automaticaly create schema tables without using this command :

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: You can issue the command from within php...? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using SchemaTool and EntityManager you can do this:

```
$schemaTool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($entityManager);
$classes = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$schemaTool->createSchema($classes);
```

Comment: how can i determine that schema is created before or not?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to see if the schema has been created. In my experience, I have simply used `$schemaTool->dropSChema($classes)` prior to creating it.

Comment: @Sina Miandashti you can also do a try-catch. `try { //here create table code} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException $exc) { //Table exists}`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you want to do it from php code, you can check how the doctrine command works and copy the code. You can find it here:

```
vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php
```

If you check the execute method, you will see how it's done. Apparently you need to get a connection through the DBAL DriverManager, which gives you access to a schema object, which in turn has a createDatabase method. I have not tried this myself.